# SSRS value not reflecting what is in the DB/DataSet

Tags: reporting-services

I have a situation in an SSRS Report wherein the report is not reflecting what is in the data.

The field in question is company-paid Long Term Disability. The value is calculated in a Stored Procedure as 0.0018 of a person's Gross Wages.  The Stored Procedure is run by the report and it populates a table with the data the report will use.  The report, then, does a straight "select" of values from that pre-populated table.

Let's use a concrete example:

- Tom Thumb has a LTD value in the DataSet of 86.3077. I'm looking at
  it as I type this, so I *know* that is the value in the source data.
- Next, I run the query in SSRS Report Designer that populates my report's DataSet, and I see the same value of 86.3077 for the field LTDInsurance.  That's the correct value. So far, so good.
- In the Design View, I can drag the field [LTDInsurance] into the
  textfield of the report, or I can use an expression. Neither approach works correctly.

  ```
  =Fields!LTDInsurance.Value
  ```
- Formatting on the field is #,##0

When I run the report, the value in that field shows 8,631 instead of 86 (Rounded 86.31).  I have deleted and recreated the field.  I've closed and reopened Visual Studio (VS 2010 can go wonky on you at times.).  I've rebooted.  I have tried a whole variety of Properties on that textfield.

Why is it showing this incorrect value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the data file (rdl.data) from the folder your rdl is in

Comment: Lemming, I would NEVER have figured that out.  Thank you very much.  So, am I correct in assuming that the rdl.data file is some sort of data cache?  I did note that the report took about 45-50 seconds to load instead of 5-10.  So I am assuming the data was cached in that file.

Comment: That's correct, has been a source of frustration for me in the past too! :-)